# DATETIME while using "range from-to" link type in icCube

Tags: iccube

On icCube tools (v 5.1.4), how can I use the link type "Range (from-to)" based on a "DateTime" type on the dimension (instead of a Date type)?

You can reproduce my problem by downloading the cube [**here**](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/data/Walkthrough_Ranged2.zip) and modifying the type of the column "Order Date" and "Ship date" to "DATETIME" instead of "DATE" (line 14 and 15).

The validation process in icCube builder throw the following error:
"link with incompatible types for dimension 'Calendar'. Dimension column 'Hour'- to fact column 'Ship date'-"

Many thanks for our help.
Philippe

Comment: Any reason why the type Range (from-to) can not be converted to a Date in the data source table ?

Comment: Our application is working on transactions which are open only few hours (winthin a day or two). Therefore working on a Date type is not enough, we need to include the time as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem between the Time Dimension Wizard and the Validation, no other workaround than not using the Time Wizard if you need an hour level.

We've open an [issue](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-210) (available from 5.1.7)